# How do I add CSS only for certain user roles?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

On all posts, I'm trying to hide the Update button, which is contained within this box:

```
<div id="postbox-container-1" class="postbox-container">
```

I only want to hide this box and button for a certain user role, 'Bookings Viewer', which I have created. Here is my code so far:

```
//Hides the update button for the Booking Viewer user role
add_action( 'wp', 'hide_update_booking_viewer' );
function hide_update_booking_viewer()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'Bookings Viewer', (array) $user->roles ) ) { ?> 
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
#postbox-container-1 {display:none;}
</style><?
}

}
```

Currently the code, which I've placed into functions.php, seems to have no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realise it's not good practise but this is just supposed to be a really quick task to stop someone hitting the wrong button by accident. I've gone through the user roles with capability manager and Adminimize to disable Write Options, but the Update button remains.

Comment: I installed your plugin and it removes the ability for me to even access the posts when I disable the 'edit' permission.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a different hook:

```
function hide_update_booking_viewer() {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'Bookings Viewer', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
'<style>
#postbox-container-1 {display:none !important;}
</style>'
} }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_update_booking_viewer' );
```

This should output the styles into the `head` section of your webpage for the user "Bookings Viewer" if you registered the user role correctly.

But, as suggested in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298971/if-user-role-is-then-echo-text) post, it is better to rely on capabilities of the user rather than on it's name.
Example:

```
function hide_update_booking_viewer_1() {
if ( current_user_can( 'read' ) ) {
'<style>
#postbox-container-1 {display:none !important;}
</style>'
} }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_update_booking_viewer_1' );
```

A list of capabilities and role types can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

Comment: I tweaked your first piece of code to print the CSS as it Wordpress was giving me a "critical error" message in its current form - still no joy. Regarding using the capabilities, would that code not mean that all roles who can read, cannot Update the post? In this case I only want Bookings Viewer to not be able to Update.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work out the answer for myself - I was adding the action to the wrong hook. wp_head is for the 'front-end' website, so we need to use 'admin_head'. I also echoed out the CSS. Finally, '#publishing-action' refers to the Update button, which is what I was trying to hide specifically.

```
//Hides the update button for the Booking Viewer user role
function hide_update_booking_viewer()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'bookings_viewer', (array) $user->roles ) ) { 
    echo('<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#publishing-action {display:none; !important}
</style>');
}

}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_booking_viewer' );
```